# Commonly occurring pattern for callbacks, but why?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've never really used JavaScript, but I know roughly what it's about. Now I'm looking through some examples of chrome extensions, and I see this "pattern" quite a lot.

```
var Main = {
    enable: function(){ window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false); },
    onMouseMove: function(event){ _onMouseMove(event) },
    _onMouseMove: function(event){
        ...lenghty implementation...
    }
}
```

My question is, why? Is this some kind of optimization?

Comment: It looks likes some code is missing; the given code isn't valid. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise and representative.

Comment: I've never seen it done triple like that (one function attaches event to another function which calls a third function), however I almost never use anonymous functions when attaching events and the reason is so that I can call the function without triggering the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're question is a little vague; but I am guessing you're asking why the developer has two `onMouseMove` methods instead of just doing all the work in one, ie:

```
var Main = {
    onMouseMove: function(event) { 
        // Why not just have the implementation here?
        // Why are we delegating it to the other method?
        _onMouseMove(event) 
    },
    _onMouseMove: function(event){
        // ...length implementation...
    }
}
```

The answer is because of how [scope is handled in JavaScript](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/).  In a nutshell, the `this` keywork in most classical OOP languages (like Java) always refers to the parent class (`Main`) in the scope of a Function - JavaScript doesn't work like this.

As there are no classical classes in JavaScript, the `this` keyword actually refers to the function which invoked it; that's why the `new` keyword makes such a difference when creating a new object via its constructor function; for example:

```
function MyConstructor = function () { 
    // Assign a member property
    this.aProperty = "An Example";
}

// Using the new keyword; a new scope is created for the call which refers to the
// object about to be created (and returned).
var withNew = new MyConstructor();
console.log(withNew.aProperty);  // 'An Example'

// Without the new keyword...
var withoutNew = MyConstructor();
console.log(withoutNew.aProperty);  // undefined

// Because we didn't use new, the calling function scope was applied, so 
// the `this` keyword resolves caller's scope.
console.log(this.aProperty)  // 'An Example'
```

By delegating from `onMouseMove` to `_onMouseMove` the scope remains bound to the `Main` object instead of being bound to the object which triggered the mouse event.  Another, more readable way of achieving this is to use a delegate, or if you're using ES5, [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var Main = {
    enable: function() {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove.bind(this), false); 
    },
    onMouseMove: function(event) { 
        // ...lengthy implementation...
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one! didn't think of it this way - the scope thingy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the way chrome extensions are implemented in general, but when I use this pattern it is specifically to protect my implementation.

Usually, your plugin will expose certain properties and functions. The user of that function can easily (even accidentally) override your exposed function. In that case, if you have your actual implementation in that function, it's gone.

UPDATE: now that you've updated the question...

I personally don't see much value in exposing both the `onMouseMove` as well as the `_onMouseMove` as part of your object. I have seen some javascript libraries written like this based on some assumption that folks will "observe convention" and treat properties prefixed with `_` as private.

Probably, I would do something like this:

```
var Main = function(){
   var _onMouseMove = function(event){ ... do stuff...};
   return {
       enable: function(){...},
       onMouseMove: _onMouseMove
   }
}
```

Comment: i would +1 if you added something about encapsulation ( not indirectly as you've done here, but directly)...

Comment: Parth: feel free. If you add a better answer, I will happily +1 yours and remove mine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't any optimization (at least as far as I know).

I don't have much knowledge about chrome extensions, just read some code sometimes, nothing serious. But the pattern that you are asking about is, as brightgarden said, to protect the implementation. In other languages you have inbuilt mechanisms for encapsulating private data. Not in js. This roughly, very roughly, seems to me kind of the module pattern - example of which is already given in brightgarden's answer. You may like to read more about design patterns implemented in js over here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Specifically here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript
for the module pattern

The actual module pattern is better and less confusing than what your example is.

Answer (score 0):

That "pattern" doesn’t have any benefits other than confuse the reader.